# Idiom or proverbs for the word "not pleasant"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

> Furthermore, the toilets should be more clean because some toilets are
>   _________ to go into.

What is the idiom or proverb that could be used for the word "not pleasant"?

Comment: The straightforward single word that means "not pleasant" is *unpleasant*.

Comment: I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) It will help you trailer your question. Remember, healthy question attracts healthy answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

> **unpleasant**, filthy, irksome, horrible, nasty, miserable, awful,
>   disgusting, dreadful, miserable, nauseating.

Whatever suits you better.

Comment: I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) It will help you trailer your answer/explantion prudently. Remember, healthy answer attracts healthy responses.

Answer (score 0):

The only idiom (from Shakespeare's "Hamlet") can be recommended:

***stink (or smell) to high heaven***

PHRASE

Have a very strong and unpleasant odor.

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stink_(or_smell)_to_high_heaven)